# Better way to run method on all page loads?

Tags: c#, blazor, load

Let's say I want to do some logging across all pages for a visitor-

On each of my pages, I have something like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    logger.log(user);
}
```

Is there a better way to tell blazor I want `logger.log` to run all ALL pages `OnInitializedAsync`? Or do I have to do it manually for each page.

Or, is there a better approach to user logging?

Answer (score 2):

Create a component that you inherit on all the pages you want to apply the logger.

I've implemented the functionality in `SetParametersAsync`, so you don't need to remember to call the base "OnInitializedAsync" every time.

```cs
public class MyPage : ComponentBase
{
    private bool _init = true;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Set the parameters
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        if (_init) 
        {        
           logger.log(user);
           _init = false;
        }

        //Call base with an empty parameter view as we've already set them
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}
```

```cs
@page "/"

@inherits MyPage

//...
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending this approach, I'm going to give this a try later!